# Get System Profiler Information without a macOS Installation

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, system-information, system-profiler

I have a bunch of factory reset MacBooks. I want to know the CPU, memory and storage configuration for each of these machines. What is the fastest way to get this information without to go through the initial setup and resetting the machines again?

I have a USB installer of macOS 10.13 and a macOS installation on an external hard drive, which needs unusually long to load on each machine.

What are my options?

Comment: The answers on the duplicate question are much better than we managed here. Please flag if we want to reopen this for a new answer if the one about booting to recovery and running System_Profiler isn’t adequate for anyone’s needs.

Answer (score 0):

Using bootable Ubuntu You can check the Computer Feature fastest.

- Make USB drive bootable with Ubuntu
- Connect that USB drive to Computer and Boot from it
- then go to about computer in dropdown menu at top right corner.
  here you will get all details of computer such as HardDisc Size, CPU, GPU, RAM,   etc

Using this method you don't have to go through time consuming installation processes.

Answer (score 0):

Bring a bootable MacOS drive to play and boot each one in sequence?

Short of having an MDM or automation solution, that would be my way to gather the data needed. For bonus points, you could even write a script on the desktop to dump the results to a file named by the serial number of the Mac and then set that script to run at log in.

Great little exercise if you wanted to learn bash scripting or knew someone that could assist with that part.